# What does Entry Validity Date mean on Dubai visit visa?

Tags: visas, dubai, visit

Recently I got a Dubai visit visa approved. Although I mentioned on the application form the date of arrival in Dubai to be 21 Dec 2023, the validity date mentioned on the approved visa page is 20 Dec 2023. Is this a mistake by the visa issuing authority, or has it been interpreted differently? Kindly note that the visa application date and approval date is 21 Nov 2023.

Comment: What is the expiration date and/or validity?

Comment: The normal English construction of "entry validity date" is that's the date the visa becomes valid or usable; the traveler may use the visa to enter the visa-issuing country on or after the visa's validity date. You're scheduled to arrive the day after the visa becomes valid, which should be no problem at all.